# Phalcon + AngularJS upload

Tags: php, angularjs, phalcon

I'm working in a form with AngularJS for the front-end and Phalcon PhP for the backend and I'm implementing a upload. I'm using [this directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-uploader) to do so. My problem is that I don't know how handle this upload on a phalcon php action.

Would you have a piece of example code so I could use to start?

Thanks for any help

Comment: check the [phalcon documentation for file uploads](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request_File.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along those lines:

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{

   public function uploadAction()
   {
      // Check if the user has uploaded files
      if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true) {

        foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file) {
            $path = 'path/to/file' . $file->getName();
            $isUploaded = $file->moveTo($path);
            echo $isUploaded;
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Of course you have to set routing to point to this controller and function.

Comment: As posted above getUploadedFiles is working for me too. But the problem was if i wanted to send multipart data - then i needed to use `json_decode($this->request->getPost('somekey'))`

Comment: sorry I didn't get that. could you post some piece of code you were working on? javascript part also

Comment: @boroboris Thanks for your answer! I will be coding then I will set the answer as the correct.